# How to insert layout within another layout at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best way to insert a layout inside another layout at runtime.  Specifically I have a FrameLayout that contains a ListView.  This is defined in one mainlayout.xml file, and I have another layout file defining the header in header.xml.

1) How do I include the headerlayout.xml defined layout inside the definition of mainlayout.xml.(static case) ie without copying everything inside but referencing the other definition.

2) How could I dynamically add header layout into specific spot in mainlayout.xml at runtime?
   I know about inflating and all that, just not sure how to attach it to the spot where I want it in the mainlayout. Since I am not including whole definition in mainlayout.xml how to I have a placeholder there and set it dynamically in the right spot after inflation.  (dynamic case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static case. Inside your `mainlayout.xml`:

```
<include layout="@layout/header" id="@+id/header" />
```

Another solution which ca be both static and dynamic is using [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html)

```
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub"
          android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
          android:layout="@layout/mySubTree"
          android:layout_width="120dip"
          android:layout_height="40dip" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I need help with this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897440/why-upper-part-of-this-layout-display