# Why upper part of this layout does not display?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my layout.  The problem is that either the PageViewer contents are visible and nothing else. If I see PageViewer to gone than I see everything above it. Also tried root layout as frame layout but it does not help.  Main thing is only the view pager is visible. What I want is 2/3 ViewPager contents which  contains data, and above some header material that is 1/3. I don't want to use weights as the upper part is already sized correctly. I just want to guarantee that both the top and pageviewer display properly.  Is it a characteristic of pageviewers that they switch everything? or can they not be applied below another element?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mHeaderHeader"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/myInclude"
    layout="@layout/myInclude_layout" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/myInclude2r"
    layout="@layout/myInclude2" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 </FrameLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/myInclude3"
    layout="@layout/myinclude3layout" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 />
   <include layout="@layout/myinclude4" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mHeaderHeader"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/myInclude"
            layout="@layout/myInclude_layout" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/myInclude2r"
            layout="@layout/myInclude2" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/myInclude3"
            layout="@layout/myinclude3layout" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/myinclude4"
        android:id="@+id/myinclude4" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBelow="@id/mHeaderHeader"
        android:layout_alignAbove="@id/myinclude4" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I suppose that ViewPager takes all space, so I placed it below header and above footer using RelativeLayout